# Restriction of $\mathcal{T}_{X / R}$ to the special fiber

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ be a flat and projective morphism of schemes over $\mathbb{C}$, where $R$ is a DVR. Assume additionally that the fibers of $f$ are Gorenstein and seminormal (in particular reduced). Let $i : X_0 \to X$ denote the closed immersion of the special fiber.

Is it then the case that the morphism of tangent sheaves $i^*\mathcal{T}_{X / R} \to \mathcal{T}_{X_0 / \mathbb{C}}$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: I recommend that you do the computation for yourself when $R$ equals $\mathbb{C}[[t]]$ and when $X$ equals $\text{Spec}(A)$ for $A=R[u,v]/\langle uv-t \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks for the counter-example. I'm in the situation where I need the cokernel $K$ (which can be thought of as the $t$-torsion elements of $\mathcal{T}^1_{X / R}$) of the above morphism to satisfy $H^1(X,K) = 0$. Any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, $K$ is supported at the singular locus of $X_0$, hence $H^1(X,K)$ vanishes if $X$ is fibered in curves. In higher dimension, I'm not so sure.

Comment: Yes, the cokernel is supported on the singular locus of $X_0$.